# Is RTL languages rendering OS dependent in Flash (Actionscript2)?

Tags: actionscript, operating-system, actionscript-2, multilingual

I'm working on a multilingual project that supports RTL (right-to-left) languages. I have data coming in from XML files to dynamic textfields. I'm using ActionScript 2 (I know, :S).

In MAC OSX, the fonts render correctly for RTL, but when I preview it in a Windows environment, the entire text gets jumbled up?

- Parenthesis are out of place
- Numerical values are thrown in wildly different positions. Such as 4G where the four is nowhere close to the "G".

Any clue as to why and/or any solutions? Thanks!

**UPDATE:** In windows whenever the text has to go multiline, even with (wordwrap = true, autoSize = true, and multiline = true), it seems to break the text.